# Why is WAIT_OBJECT_0 defined as ((STATUS_WAIT_0 ) + 0 )

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In the `winbase.h` header, you can find the following line:

```
#define WAIT_OBJECT_0       ((STATUS_WAIT_0 ) + 0 )
```

`STATUS_WAIT_0` is defined in the `winnt.h` header as such:

```
#define STATUS_WAIT_0       ((DWORD)0x00000000L)
```

And `DWORD` is typedef'd to `unsigned long`.

My question is, why is `0` added to the `STATUS_WAIT_0` value?

Comment: Why does it matter? What is the programming problem you're having where the exact text of the definition makes a difference? It could be defined as `(7 * 3 - 21)` for all you care.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two possible reasons.  The first is readability.  If
there is a series of `#define`s:

```
#define WAIT_OBJECT_0 ((STATUS_WAIT_0) + 0)
#define WAIT_OBJECT_1 ((STATUS_WAIT_0) + 1)
//  ...
```

In this case, it makes sense to specify `((STATUS_WAIT_0) + 0)`
for reasons of orthogonality: you are defining a series of
values based on `STATUS_WAIT_0`, and it is just by accident that
this one happens to offset by `0`, rather than some other value.

The second possible reason involves integral promotion.  The
author wanted `WAIT_OBJECT_0` to have the promoted type of
`STATUS_WAIT_0`, regardless of the type of `STATUS_WAIT_0`.  The
addition ensures integral promotion.

Comment: Not that I know but does promotion matter here? Given that both the operands of `+` are integrals? The base is a `long` and offset is an `int`.

Comment: @legends2k It matters precisely because both operands are integral types.  What happens when I use `WAIT_OBJECT_0` as an operand to a template function, or a function overloaded for different integral types, may be different with or without the addition.

Comment: Aah... template type deduction, overload resolution, etc. depend on the exact type, going with the cosest match. Now I see the reason for invoking integral promotion. Thanks James.

Comment: Those header files date back to a time when C++ had not been invented, i.e. a time when neither overloads nor templates were anything to consider. Ensuring type promotion is a lucky coincidence, not a judicious decision.

Comment: @IInspectable The rules for integral promotion come from C, and are the same in C and in C++.  The effects are more visible in C++, but they can also play a role in C---things like the type passed to a `...`.

Comment: That's true, I hadn't considered the evil ellipsis. Maybe it wasn't a lucky coincidence after all. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: What means 'signaled the object' ?

Answer (score 5):

One important point that the other answers haven't addressed is that `STATUS_WAIT_0` is one of the possible values of `NTSTATUS` ([NTSTATUS Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx)).  `NTSTATUS` is used primarily when writing device drivers.

When you perform a `WaitFor...` on a *thing*, it's possible that execution will drop down into the kernel, and depending on what you're waiting for the result from the device driver will be an `NTSTATUS` type (1)

For this reason it makes sense that the result of a Wait in user-mode is based on the result of a Wait in kernel mode, hence:

```
#define WAIT_OBJECT_0 ((STATUS_WAIT_0 ) + 0 )
```

Now, as to why we add the zero... as James Kanze states, it makes things much more readable in the cases where `WAIT_OBJECT_1` were defined.  Consistency is an important part of maintainability.

As for why `STATUS_WAIT_0` is cast to a `DWORD`... it's because the value of `0x0L` as a constant will vary depending on compiler, so the cast ensures you know exactly how big the type is.

---

(1) not being a writer of device drivers, I can make no assumptions that this statement is true 100% of the time, but it makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

As you've already mentioned, as far as the compiler is concerned, there is no difference in value between `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, `STATUS_WAIT_0` and `0`.

However, there is a difference in what is communicated to a maintenance programmer.  The line:

```
#define WAIT_OBJECT_0       ((STATUS_WAIT_0 ) + 0 )
```

says that `WAIT_OBJECT_0` is the same as `STATUS_WAIT_0`, but it doesn't have to be.  The line says that the value represented by `WAIT_OBJECT_0` can change with no consequence.  However, if it was written as:

```
#define WAIT_OBJECT_0       STATUS_WAIT_0
```

This would indicate that they are equivalent and are (potentially) linked together somehow.

Alternatively, it could just be in the coding standard.

Comment: Well, that's what comments are for. Not that I can think of a better reason, but a comment would be much better here.

Comment: @Gorpik Why comment when you can express the same thing, much more clearly, directly in the code?

Comment: @JamesKanze Because I don't think that's clear at all. If it was so clear, we would not have a question. Your own answer is different from this one, so again it is not so clear.

Comment: @Gorpik The first part of my answer is basically the same as this one, expressed in different terms.  It's a software engineering issue; the addition is part of an effort to make the code more readable (and thus to require less comments).

Comment: @JamesKanze You assume that `WAIT_OBJECT_0` is part of a series of `#define`s, but this answer doesn't. This makes a big difference. In fact, I have just opened `winbase.h` and it is not part of a series. I still think that the meaning of that `+ 0` is not obvious at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a style of defining macros which are a family, where the members of the family are dependant on the base value.

```
#define NONE 0
#define UNITY  (NONE + 1)
#define COUPLE (NONE + 2)
#define TRIPLE (NONE + 3)
```

Later, during maintenance, if it's decided that the base value should be made 60, then changing `NONE` to 60 would change all of them since they're defined atop the base macro. Another way it's done is

```
#define NONE 0
#define UNO  (NONE + 1)
#define DUO  (UNO + 1)
#define TRIO (DUO + 1)
```

In this specific instance, the base value and the first wait object value is set the same since the developer wanted the same integral value to denote both of them.

Comment: Of course, anyone using this style would add parentheses, so that expressions like `2 * TRIPLE` would give the expected results.

Comment: Thanks for noting! Since I'm using `const` these days instead of macros, my C is a bit rusty.